# Creating a log file compatible with splunk in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, logging, splunk

I'm trying to create a log file that splunk will read in and index. Using Splunk's [Common Information Model](http://www.splunk.com/base/Documentation/4.1.6/Knowledge/UnderstandandusetheCommonInformationModel), I have formatted my logs like so:

```
2011-30-07 12:30:37 name="Name" event_id=00001 src_ip=192.168.0.1 src_port=59176
2011-30-07 12:31:35 name="Name" event_id=00001 src_ip=192.168.0.1 src_port=59176
2011-30-07 12:32:02 name="Name" event_id=00001 src_ip=192.168.0.1 src_port=59176
etc...
```

However, when I load a log file into Splunk it reads this all as one log and doesn't split them up! To write the log out in c# I'm using a StreamWriter and at the end I was printing `\r\n`, but I've also tried `Environment.NewLine` (which apparently does the same thing).

Neither of these seem to work and therefore do not index separately! Does anyone have experience with Splunk and know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used splunk, so i really don't know if i'm correct.

But if i take a look at the specs (link you provided) their seem to use double quotes and in your example you entered single quotes. So maybe all you have to do is replace `name='Name'` by `name="Name"`?

Another point could be that you must give some informations for the tags `vendor` or `product` to get some split up?

But that's all speculative, cause i really don't know the tool.

#### Update

After a little digging into their site you can see at their [comparison sheet](http://www.splunk.com/view/free-vs-enterprise/SP-CAAAE8W) you can get also basic support for the free version. So maybe just take the [support access you like](http://www.splunk.com/support) and get an answer from the creators of the tool. Their should definitely know why your messages are not working.

Comment: Oops I had tested the quotes, I ment to have doubles in the question... As far as the vendor and product goes, they are not mandatory fields so I don't see why that will affect it. I will try tho as an experiment, thanks for your help!

Comment: Well I'm not using the free version anyway, but that's what I've had to do for now!

Comment: maybe you can provide the answer if you got it from them. Otherwise just delete the question.

Comment: Yea was planning too, haven't heard back yet. I may have to update this in a day or two!

Comment: @ing0: You accepted my answer, but i'm missing an explanation from you, cause i didn't gave a *real* answer. So what was the root of your problem?

Comment: Updated! Sorry have been busy today! :p

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oliver for getting me half way there. I contacted one of the dev support people at Splunk and while they didn't see the answer, I figured it out for myself.

While Splunk is very good at working out dates with log files, if it can't recognise the date format it will not parse it and therefore put the whole string in as an event! The problem was that the date was in the wrong format... i.e Y-d-m when it should have been Y-m-d!

Answer (score 0):

Just use log4net, and use the syslog module.

Point syslog at a udp listener on splunk.

And then presto!  Works great!

(We have it working perfectly, but are dumping splunk 'cause it is toooo expensive.  Look before you leap!)